# How to know the button pressed among buttons in the div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div of 4 buttons, when I click on any button it redirects to the same page for all the buttons, I want to know which button the user has pressed before going to the next page, I've been trying, but couldn't find that.

Here is my code :

```js
             
     $( "#buttons" ).click(function() {
    alert('button'); 
window.location.href = "score.html";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="countdown"></p>
<div id="buttons">
<button type="button" id="button1">button 1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2">button 2</button>
<button type="button" id="button3">button 3</button>
<button type="button" id="button4">button 4</button>
  </div>
```

Do you have any idea

Comment: try `alert($(this).attr('id'));`

Comment: Have you noticed that `#button` is none of your actual `<button>` elements?

Comment: @cari: No. Don't use jQuery to get an element's `id`.

Comment: @Cerbrus: of course you are right, but thats nothing to get mad about. anyway thats not the problem here. moreover, its that he adds the click listener to `#buttons` instead of `button`. Let him learn the logic first, then he can try to switch from jquery to js.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I think the OP is intentionally using delegation there. (Though not the full-on kind `.on` can help with.)

Comment: @cari: Usually, you try to teach someone the _basics_ of a programming language, before you teach someone to use a library.

Comment: @Cerbrus: this is true, but you seem to get it wrong: in this case, the basic is the program logic, and the language is jquery.

Comment: JQuery is _not_ a language. It doesn't get more basic than getting a element's `id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The element that the `click` started in is available as `target` on the event object passed into your handler, so *(but see more below)*:

```js
// Accept the event arg -------v
$( "#buttons" ).click(function(e) {
    alert('button: ' + e.target.id); // <=== Use e.target.id to get its ID
    // window.location.href = "score.html"; (commented out for live demo)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="countdown"></p>
<div id="buttons">
<button type="button" id="button1">button 1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2">button 2</button>
<button type="button" id="button3">button 3</button>
<button type="button" id="button4">button 4</button>
  </div>
```

Note that that will do the alert whenever there's a click inside the `#buttons` `div`, **even if it's not on a button**. If you only want clicks on the buttons, you can use a selector with `.on` to only call you when the click went through a button. It will call your handler as though you had hooked the handler directly to the buttons, even though in fact you've hooked it to the `#button` div, and so we use `this.id` for the ID:

```js
$( "#buttons" ).on("click", "button", function() {
    alert('button: ' + this.id);
    // window.location.href = "score.html"; (commented out for live demo)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="countdown"></p>
<div id="buttons">
<button type="button" id="button1">button 1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2">button 2</button>
<button type="button" id="button3">button 3</button>
<button type="button" id="button4">button 4</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I would not bound clicks to the parent at all, if I'm interested in `<button>` only. Eventually `$("#button").find("button")` for performance reason.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If you're concerned about performance, you wouldn't use `$("#button").find("button")`... it would be better to remove that unneeded `.find()` method..  `$("#button button")`..besides, there will actually be little to no performance differences.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: You're not going to see any performance difference, this is processing a click. You might have a point for, say, `mousemove`, but even then we're talking an immediate parent, I doubt you could ever really see a difference. But direct binding has the issue of complicating things if you add buttons dynamically.